# Use a Javascript variable from a function in another function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I know there are many posts about this topic but I couldn’t use any of them for my needs. The purpose is to use the variable **seconddivval** in the datepicker and show the available dates.

I have a PHP foreach loop with a hidden input

```
<td class='myArray'>
<input type="hidden" class="activedates" value="<?php echo "['".implode("','",$newactivedate)."'];"; ?>">
```

When clicking on myArray, this Javascript function returns the value of the above input

```
$('.myArray').click(function() {
    seconddivval = $(this).find('input.activedates').val();
});
```

All the above work fine but I need to use the variable **seconddivval** in this function

```
function available(date) {

  dmy = date.getDate() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + 
date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, seconddivval) != -1) {
return [true, ""];
   } else {
return [false,""];
  }
}

$(".datefromavailable").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: 'M dd, yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    beforeShowDay: available,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {

        $(".datetoavailable").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        var days_to_add = 365, // SET DAYS HERE
        parsed_date = new Date($.datepicker.parseDate('M dd, yy', selectedDate)),
        add_year = new Date(parsed_date.setDate(parsed_date.getDate() + days_to_add)),
        formatted_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('M dd, yy', add_year);

        $(".datetoavailable").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', formatted_date);
        $(this).parent().next().children().focus();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).next().datepicker('show')
        },0);
    }
});

$(".datetoavailable").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: 'M dd, yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    beforeShowDay: available,
    maxDate: '+1y'
});
});
```

I am sure it is simple but I can’t find the way to make it happen.

I tried everything I could think about. I declared the variable outside the function, I removed the var, I added **window.seconddivval;** to the click function, I added return at the end of the function,…

I even tried the below, which I thought would be the correct way. It works fine if I only have one array but if I have more than one array, it only returns the first array:

```
var seconddivval = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $newactivedate) . '"]'; ?>;
```

This foreach loop also works but also returns the first array:

```
var seconddivval = new Array();
<?php foreach($newactivedate as $key => $val){ ?>
    seconddivval.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
<?php } ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**
Here is how `$newactivedate` is formed:

```
$sqlactivedate = $bddp->prepare("SELECT (nullif(Adate1,'')),(nullif(Adate2,'')),(nullif(Adate3,'')),‌​(nullif(Adate4,'')),‌​(nullif(Adate5,'')),‌​(nullif(Adate6,'')),‌​(nullif(Adate7,'')),‌​(nullif(Adate8,'')),‌​(nullif(Adate9,'')),‌​(nullif(Adate10,'')) 
FROM prices WHERE id_prices = '$id_prices'");

$sqlactivedate->execute();
$rowactivedate = array();

while ($rowactivedate = $sqlactivedate -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $newactivedate = array();
  $newactivedate = array_filter($rowactivedate);
```

These are the 2 rows fetched from the database:

```
Room1 → {"(nullif(Adate1,''))":"15-8-2017","(nullif(Adate2,''))":"16-8-2017","(nullif(Adate3,''))":"17-8-2017","(nullif(Adate4,''))":"18-8-2017","(nullif(Adate5,''))":"20-8-2017","(nullif(Adate6,''))":"21-8-2017","(nullif(Adate7,''))":"22-8-2017","(nullif(Adate8,''))":"25-8-2017","(nullif(Adate9,''))":"26-8-2017","(nullif(Adate10,''))":"28-8-2017"}

Room2 → {"(nullif(Adate1,''))":"1-8-2017","(nullif(Adate2,''))":"2-8-2017","(nullif(Adate3,''))":"4-8-2017","(nullif(Adate4,''))":"5-8-2017","(nullif(Adate5,''))":"28-8-2017","(nullif(Adate6,''))":"29-8-2017","(nullif(Adate7,''))":"4-9-2017","(nullif(Adate8,''))":"5-9-2017","(nullif(Adate9,''))":"6-9-2017","(nullif(Adate10,''))":"7-9-2017"}
```

Comment: Where are you calling function `available`?

Comment: In the datepicker:        $(".datefromavailable").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'M dd, yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        beforeShowDay: available,

Comment: Why not `if ($.inArray(dmy, $(this).find('input.activedates').val()) != -1) {`? Why it's needed for user to click on `myArray`?

Comment: I don't get your "first array" thing... Can you post the structure of `$newactivedate` ?

Comment: Yes, sure. Here it is. I hope this helps: $sqlactivedate = $bddp->prepare("SELECT (nullif(Adate1,'')),(nullif(Adate2,'')),(nullif(Adate3,'')),(nullif(Adate4,'')),(nullif(Adate5,'')),(nullif(Adate6,'')),(nullif(Adate7,'')),(nullif(Adate8,'')),(nullif(Adate9,'')),(nullif(Adate10,'')) FROM prices WHERE id_prices = '$id_prices'");
$sqlactivedate->execute();

$rowactivedate = array();
while ($rowactivedate = $sqlactivedate -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 $newactivedate = array();
  $newactivedate = array_filter($rowactivedate);

Comment: @Spectarion I thought this would be a good option (to click on myArray). It returns the correct values (since I have a PHP loop) but I cannot use them in the other function. I tried your idea but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think `$newactivedate` gets overwritten at each `while` iteration... There is still something missing in the puzzle. Don't you have an `array_push` somewhere ?

Comment: No, I don't. And the JS code is outside the PHP loop. Also, the PHP code to get $newactivedate is inside this PHP foreach loop:

<?php foreach($idprices as $valuereference) {
$id_prices = $valuereference['id_prices'];

Also, I wanted to see if I got the right array when clicking on myArray so I added this $("#theval").html(seconddivval); to the click function and I do get the correct values.

Comment: I just posted a PHP way to echo all dates in one JS array... But there also is the JS way to re-format it "from the format you have in the text input...". Have you tryed it?

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
if ($.inArray(dmy, seconddivval) != -1) {
```

You are looking if a value exists in an array...
But `seconddivval` **isn't** an array.

It is a string like `"['2017-07-04','2017-07-05','2017-07-06']"`

You have to make it an array.
So from the format you have in the text input... It would be:

```
var seconddivval_asArray = seconddivval.substr(1,seconddivval.length-2).replace(/'/g,"").split(",");
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/RZKjWm?editors=1111)

**A great idea would be** to `echo` your array in a JS variable directly... Instead of echoing it in a text input...

---

**EDIT**

Okay... We'll start this from your PHP.

`$newactivedate` should be defined before the `while` loop.
And we will push the data inside... And avoid to completely overwrite it.

```
$newactivedate = [];
while ($rowactivedate = $sqlactivedate -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

  array_push($newactivedate, array_filter($rowactivedate));
  //...
}
```

You now have an array containing arrays...
We'll "stringify it" in order to be able to echo it straight in a JS variable.

```
$newactivedate_string = json_encode($newactivedate);
```

Then echo that in a JS variable:

```
var seconddivval = <?php echo $newactivedate_string; ?>;
```

Now, you have in JS, the same "array of arrays" you had in PHP.
So the `available(date)` function should be modified a little... to look in each "inner array".

```
function available(date) {

  dmy = date.getDate() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + 
  date.getFullYear();

  for(i=0;i<seconddivval.length;i++){

    if ($.inArray(dmy, seconddivval[i]) != -1) {
      return [true, ""];
     } else {
      return [false,""];
    }
  }
}
```

---

And declaring the variable outside the function is the way to go.
;)

Comment: `"['2017-07-04','2017-07-05','2017-07-06']"` is not valid `JSON`

Comment: I added JSON.parse but the console log displays: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Do you mean like this: $json = json_encode($newactivedate); and then this in the hidden input: <?php echo "['".implode("','",$json)."'];"; ?>

Comment: @Daniela Valid `JSON` at an attribute value which can be passed to `JSON.parse()` should take the form `value='["2017-07-04","2017-07-05","2017-07-06"]'`. Note the placement of single quotes and double quotes

Comment: @Daniela: here is something else to try... ;) Oups... I just added som double quotes to it...

Comment: @Louys "Merge all the values in one" will merge the 2 or more arrays I can have? If this is the case, it won't work in my case since 1 array = 1 room. This is why I had to create a while loop. But I will try what you are suggesting :)

Comment: And in this particular case, there are 2 rows fetched from the data base: Room1 and Room2 with their respective available dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can `echo` a valid `JSON` string from `php` using `json_encode()` at `.ready()` alias `$()` and get the response with `$.getJSON()`

```
$(function() {
  var seconddivval;
  $.getJSON("/path/to/server")
  .then(function(json) {
    seconddivval = json; // global though we will use the variable with `.then()`
    $(".myArray.input.activedates").data()
    function available(date) {
      dmy = date.getDate() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + 
      date.getFullYear();
      if ($.inArray(dmy, seconddivval) != -1) {
        return [true, ""];
      } else {
        return [false,""];
      }
    }
    $(".datefromavailable").datepicker(
      {minDate: 0, dateFormat: 'M dd, yy', changeMonth: true
      , changeYear: true, numberOfMonths: 2, beforeShowDay: available
    }); 
      }, function err(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.error(errorThrown)
  })
})
```

Comment: @Louys I had the same idea to echo the array in JS but it only returns the first array I have in the PHP foreach loop.

Comment: Also, for this helps: I know the array is not correctly declared in JS with single and double quotes. I believe the correct is
var secondivval = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $newactivedate) . '"]'; ?>; 
but for some reason if I use this code directly in the hidden input → the console log returns this → "var secondivval = ["

Comment: Have you tried `echo`ing  result of `json_encode()` to `$.getJSON()` call? If set at an attribute at HTML you will need to call `JSON.parse()` with the `.value` of the element passed to get an `Array` instead of a `String`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very good at this. How do I do that? Like this $json = json_encode($newactivedate); and then echo $json ?

Comment: I tried but since my datepicker is longer than the one I submitted before (sorry I didn't think this would affect the query I had to use a JS variable in another function) I have to adapt your procedure to my code. I just submitted to whole datepicker code.

Comment: It is still showing **seconddivval** as not defined :(

Comment: @Daniela What does `console.log(json)` within first function at `.then()` log at `console`?

Comment: not defined. Maybe I didn't write correctly the PHP code? This is what I did **$json = json_encode($newactivedate);**
Also this is what echo the $json: string(1) "1" {"(nullif(Adate1,''))":"15-8-2017","(nullif(Adate2,''))":"16-8-2017","(nullif(Adate3,''))":"17-8-2017","(nullif(Adate4,''))":"18-8-2017","(nullif(Adate5,''))":"20-8-2017","(nullif(Adate6,''))":"21-8-2017","(nullif(Adate7,''))":"22-8-2017","(nullif(Adate8,''))":"25-8-2017","(nullif(Adate9,''))":"26-8-2017","(nullif(Adate10,''))":"28-8-2017"} and I also echo it in the hidden input → value="<?php echo $json; ?>"

Comment: I don't know why the arrays are correctly displayed for each of the room but I cannot get the correct array in the datepicker. I just edited my query with the 2 different rows fetched from the database.

Comment: @Daniela Have minimal experienced using `php`. What do `php` server logs and `Network` tab at browser log for `$.getJSON()` request?

Comment: Why do you call `.datepicker()` multiple times?

Comment: On my side, it's with JS that I have minimal experience :( I am not sure I understood properly your query but the [Network] tab doesn't show any error and I don't see any error on PHP side. There is no way to use the JS variable that I have in the function when clicked on the hidden input?

Comment: The issue is not with the datepicker. For example, if I declare this **var secondivval = ["23-7-2017","24-7-2017","25-7-2017","21-8-2017","25-8-2017","20-8-2017"];** The datepicker works perfectly and shows only the available dates. The issue is that the PHP variable **$newactivedate** is the result of a while loop with one or more arrays depending on how many rows are fetched.

Comment: @Daniela As mentioned previously have little experience with `php`. Is issue reducing multiple arrays to a single array?

Comment: Yes, I know. No worries :) I don't have any issue if the PHP query fetches only one row but it is unfortunately not always the case as one house can have several rooms with different available dates. I thought I was doing it correctly but it's not the case. I believe I have to rethink how to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my mistakes and I am posting them here for it can help someone else:

1.- Declare **seconddivval** within the function **available(date)**:

`var seconddivval = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $newactivedate) . '"]'; ?>;`

Strangely it only returns the last row of arrays if declared outside.

2.- I removed the **$(document).ready(function() **

3.- I should have written the JS script just before the end of the PHP while loop. That way it takes the correct row (I wrongly thought it was easier to use a click function...but making mistakes it's how we learn...).

Thank you all of you who tried to help me in solving this issue!